# Simple paint program to adjust alpha values

Tags: software

I am looking for the most simplest of paint programs for adjusting the alphavalues of a picture. I only need a brush that will let me adjust the alpha values.

I have GIMP installed, but am a total noob with it, and simply want to change the alpha channels by brush. Is this a weird question? I figure this wouldn't be so extraordinary right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a GIMP expert, but I've learned a ton about it from Meet The Gimp, a site with tutorials and forums for questions. Site URL is
http://blog.meetthegimp.org/

Lots of folks there who really understand GIMP.